# In mail composer is is possible to load the body from user input

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, email

Instead of using a default body with @"" is it possible to load the body from 1 or 2 UITextFields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you set any string value to mail message body, e.g.:

```
MFMailComposeViewController* mailComposer = ... //Create and setup controller
NSString *messageBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Text from first field:%@\nText from first field: %@", firstField.text, secondTextField.text];
[mailComposer setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:NO];
```

passing YES to 2nd parameter also allows you to format your message using html tags.

Comment: @user613231 Notice that he is using %@ formatters to inject the strings from the other text fields.  the number of formatters must match the number of strings that you are passing in.  Otherwise, if you only have two formatters, only the first two strings will get injected into the new NSString.